# React update component state from child component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from './header.jsx';
import Footer from './footer.jsx';

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
  }
  toggleWrapper() {
    this.setState({open: !true});
  }
  render () {
    const toggle = this.state.open ? 'open' : '';
    return (
        <section className={"wrapper " + toggle}>
            <div className="inner-wrapper">
                <Header action={this.toggleWrapper.bind(this)}/>
                    {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

and I am trying to update its state from its header (child) component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

import Logo from './logo.jsx';

class Header extends React.Component {
  toggleNavigation() {
    {this.props.action}
  }
  render () {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <button onClick={this.toggleNavigation.bind(this)} 
                    className="menu-icon hide-for-large" 
                    type="button">
            </button>
            <Logo />
            <nav className="main-nav">
                <li>
                    <Link to='/'>about us</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/projects'>projects</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to=''>production</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to=''>area director</Link>
                </li>
            </nav>
            <i className="fa fa-envelope-o float-right contact-us-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </header>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

I am trying to pass "toggleWrapper" method as a prop so that I can change the state with a click event inside the header component.

However nothing happens on my screen when I click on the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but your code has two problems: first of all, your upper component's `toggleWrapper` function does not actually change the state to anything other than `false` (or rather, `!true`). Fix it like this:

```js
toggleWrapper() {
  this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
}
```

Secondly the `toggleNavigation` function in your child component does not actually call the function. You don't even actually need a separate function in this case, you could simply do this:

```js
<button onClick={this.props.action} ...
```